# take specific data from a list in php

Tags: php

I have a string like this:

```
 house1- a normal house 

 house2-an office  

 house3-a scholl
```

There are about 2000 lines. I want to get only house1,house2,house3 etc. from that it and put it in another file. Like:

```
 house1

 house2 

 house3
```

I understand that the explode function works for separating strings, but how can I do this?

Comment: That's not valid PHP, can you show a sample of actual code? Wild guess: try `$array['house3']` etc etc...

Comment: Can you try and be more clear? It's hard to tell what you're asking.

Comment: Just edited, need more details ?

Comment: I think you should use regex to find all texts from a file which has the word 'house' inside them, but the number changes right? like house1, house2... If that is what you meant, then there is a greate tutorial here http://weblogtoolscollection.com/regex/regex.php

Comment: Oh I see you're trying to parse a string?

Comment: What is the actual question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$fContents = file( 'path/to/your/file' );
foreach ( $fContents as $row )
    file_put_contents( 'path/to/other/file', explode( '-', $row )[0] , FILE_APPEND );
```

Shitty but working example (assuming you got 5.4+).

---

for PHP 5.3:

```
$fContents = file( 'path/to/your/file' );
foreach ( $fContents as $row )
{
    $firstField = explode( '-', $row );
    file_put_contents( 'path/to/other/file', $firstField[0] , FILE_APPEND );
}
```

Comment: what about if the sting is like :  house1-office-in capital city . 
if i want to just take house1 ?

Comment: explode would then split your string into an array of 3 strings
("house1", "-office", "-in capital city")
as we just use the first element of that array (index 0) it does not matter to us wether there's any more "-" in that line or not

Comment: You don't need 5.4, just create a variable for the explode before you fetch the index.

Comment: @m02ph3u5 , 
it is showing error " Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in .....line 4 " after trying that code.

Comment: well, what PHP version do you have?

Comment: @m02ph3u5 
ok, may be the the last line will be ..... explode( '-', $row [0]) instead of .....explode( '-', $row )[0] . ?

Comment: @m02ph3u5 
it is almost ok. but it is only post the last string of list. 
( i. e : home3)

Comment: did you set the FILE_APPEND flag?

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "house1- a normal house";

$result = explode("-", $str)[0];

var_dump($result);
```

Assuming the latest PHP version (5.4.x).

Comment: i know that bro. but it is almost 2000 lists. So, i have to write 2000 strings ?

Comment: @rethom: How is the list represented? A large string? An array? Since you didn't gave us that information, despite us asking it for you, that's what you get from me.

Comment: Just explode newlines first, then explode each of those pieces by the dash.

Comment: No array, just a simple list.

Comment: @rethom: In which case `explode` by newlines first, and then foreach this code on each element.